# Download folder from server to local iPad / iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, download

I want to create an application that automatically downloads a folder from my own server and store it locally on the iPad/iPhone. How can i accomplish this and where does the folder get stored on the local iDevice ? Therefore how will i access it afterwards? Many thanks for your help

Comment: instead of down voting it would be more helpful to actually help , if i knew how to do it i wouldn't ask

Comment: This is too broad, you need to come up with a plan, implement it and then ask questions about specific problems you have. There are many tutorials online to help with general data storage.

Comment: iOS devices don't have a generic file system that is available to all applications.  Your application can create files within it's own sandbox - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Check out Apple's FTP example. Also check this out: https://github.com/intruder29108/FtpBrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do so was actually putting all the pictures for example in one zip file, downloading it and unzipping it on the real device using this code :

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(
                                                   DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someDirectory/newPics.zip"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    // 2
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];

    if(!error)
    {
        // 3
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *zipPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics.zip"];

        [data writeToFile:zipPath options:0 error:&error];

        if(!error)
        {

            ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
            // 1
            if ([za UnzipOpenFile: zipPath]) {
                // 2
                BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo: path overWrite: YES];
                if (NO == ret){} [za UnzipCloseFile];

                // 3
                NSString *imageFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"newPics/pic1.png"];
                //[self removeImage:zipPath];


                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:zipPath error: &error];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageFilePath];
                        [_webV loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL]];



                });

            }

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error saving file %@",error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error downloading zip file: %@", error);
    }

});
```

It's the best way to do it , fast and reliable.